# Frequency warping while creating filter coefficients

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, filter-design, lowpass-filter, digital-filters

If I have an audio signal at 16kHz with frequencies band-limited to 8kHz. I want to low-pass filter this signal such that fc=4000Hz. Meaning when I reconstruct the signal I do not want any content above 4kHz.

In order to use the matlab/python functions to generate the filter coeffs to do this job, ex fir1(), should I specify the cut-off frequency as 0.5 or do I need to do some frequency mapping such that my digital cut-off freq (fc) should correspond to analog cut-off of 4kHz?

Thanks

Comment: The documentation of matlab functions in general is very good, so have a look on the function you want to use and you will see there some examples too ...